# Ensuring new sign up members use a unique name

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I am using Azure B2C to sign up users which by default includes email, display name and so on

However my app lends itself to a certain level of social media style interacting ensuring display names are unique, to prevent misidentification, for example on a public user board (where email or anything actually personal would be inappropriate)

I can easily customise the B2C sign up process with extra fields but not, as far as I can tell, make it easy to run any logic during sign up to ensure nobody has taken that name

I don't want to add another check within the app since this would not be a nice user experience, since this would effectively be a two stage sign up process

Can anyone advise how I could incorporate some level of validation within sign up that would achieve this?

From the guidelines: Note that it seems clear to me here you could not piggyback any of the sign in logic since it's all bound into the 'API' div?

```
<h1>My B2C Application</h1>
<div id="api"></div>   <!-- Leave this element empty because Azure AD B2C will insert content here. -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you need to use custom policies.

During the sign-up flow, you can read AAD to check for duplicates.

**Update**

If you want to ensure that the displayName is unique across AAD, then the easiest way is to use a [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-custom-rest-api-netfw) in the user journey.

The REST API does a [search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet?tabs=applications#search-users) with a $filter.

(Although the documentation is ambiguous as regards what can be in the filter expression).

I don't know of any way of doing this search in the custom policy directly.

Comment: Would you be able to give me a sample of how that code might look?

Comment: OK thank you, I have managed to configure and upload custom policy framework, am now working through the tutorial on hooking that into a restful API

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `user name` based user flow/custom policies. So user name will always be unique. User will be able to login using user name since its unique.

In tenant config,  in identity providers blade, choose 'local account'  to be user name type. Crate a user flow which uses `user name`.

Comment: So this would be a custom flow and not "Sign up and sign in"? I wish there were some way to use the OOTB one. It is such a common scenario (display name, email, and password), sow the display name can be seen by the community w/o giving away the email.

Comment: @lcj - as I mentioned you can use a user flow as well. User flows are OOTB solutions. If you check in identity provider blade you can see option for user name